# Количество чётных чисел в матрице

Tags: c, массивы, матрицы

Есть матрица `10*10` с целыми числами. Необходимо узнать количество чётных чисел в ней:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROWS 10
#define COLS 10

int main(void)
{
   int array[ROWS][COLS];
   for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
       {
           printf("array[%d][%d]=", i, j);
           scanf("%d", &array[i][j]);
       }
   }
   printf("\n");
   for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
   {
       for(int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
       {
           printf("%d ", array[i][j]);

       }
       printf("\n");
   }




}
```

Comment: Вы умеете проверять что число чётное?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы узнать количество четных чисел в матрице, нужно добавить счетчик, который будет увеличиваться каждый раз, когда встречается четное число. После того, как матрица будет просканирована, можно вывести результат счетчика.

Ниже приведен пример кода, который решает задачу:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROWS 10
#define COLS 10

int main(void)
{
   int array[ROWS][COLS];
   for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
       {
           printf("array[%d][%d]=", i, j);
           scanf("%d", &array[i][j]);
       }
   }
   printf("\n");
   int evenCount = 0; // счетчик четных чисел
   for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
   {
       for(int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
       {
           if (array[i][j] % 2 == 0) // если число четное
           {
               evenCount++; // увеличиваем счетчик
           }
       }
   }
   printf("Количество четных чисел: %d\n", evenCount);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Добавляем в начало переменную, например `int count = 0;`
2. Во втором цикле (вместо этого `printf("%d ", array[i][j]);`) проверяем делится ли число на 2 (`array[i][j] % 2 == 0`)
3. Если число делится на 2: `count++;`
4. Выводим `count`

Answer (score 0):

Второй цикл не нужен

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROWS 10
#define COLS 10
int evenCount = 0; // счетчик четных чисел
int main(void)
    {
    int array[ROWS][COLS];
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            {
            printf("array[%d][%d]=", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &array[i][j]);
            if (array[i][j] % 2 == 0) evenCount++; // если число четное увеличиваем счетчик
            }
        }
    
    printf("\nКоличество четных чисел: %d\n", evenCount);
    return 0;
    }
```